# Facebook PhoneGap Plugin. Gets FB Access Token fine, FB ID is undefined?

Tags: facebook, cordova

Ive been bashing my head for a few hours now. Ive finally integrated the Phonegap Facebook plugin into my application, but whenever I do:

```
FB.api('/me', function(me){
    alert("ID: "+me.id);
});
```

or

```
var fbid = "1";
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status == 'connected') {
        fbid = response.authResponse.userID;
        var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    //  alert(response.authResponse.userID);
    //  alert(response.authResponse.accessToken);
    etc...
```

The token is fine, but the ID alerts are always 'undefined' which seems weird because you need the ID to get the token if im correct?

Answer (score 1):

`FB.getLoginStatus` does not return the user's facebook ID nor does it return the `signedRequest` string. It does return an `accessToken` which you can then use to get the user's FB id via https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[accessToken]. That will give you a JSON object that has the user's information (if the `accessToken` is valid).